# In Intellij, can I choose which log tab is selected by default when I start an appserver?

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish-2.x

I'm using glassfish, but that may not matter.  When I start glassfish, I'd like it to open up the Glassfish Log that I have highlighted here

[image: glassfish log]

But it always defaults to the `Output` tab instead so I always have to do that extra click.  Not a huge deal but I rarely care about that tab.  I'm using the latest Intellij-IDEA 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the tab, select **Focus on Startup** in the menu.